# Cannot remove records using MS Access frontend

Tags: sql, vba, postgresql, ms-access, odbc

I'm stuck on a problem with removing a record through MS Access frontend. On the dialog form I've put the button and in the onclick event I've created a sub with VBA command `RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord`.

Execution seems to proceed, I receive warning about removing single record from database, and after I hit OK and refresh nothing happens. In fact removed record is still there.

Moreover, I've tried to remove it from the MS Access query (on which the form is based) and still no luck - again the confirmation window appears, and after clicking OK button and refresh the record persists in table.

I've successfully removed record directly from rdbms (Postgresql 9,4 ODBC connected to MS Access frontend by connection string and linking tables). No additional info in Postgresql logs. Seems like everything should work, but it doesn't. And no any error messages. Could you please give me any suggestions on this?

Here is the SQL query:

```sql
SELECT inventory.inventory_id, inventory.serial_number, inventory.registry_number,
       inventory.year_of_manufacture, inventory.description, 
       inventory.assortment_id_assortment, inventory.personnel_id_personnel,
       inventory.classification_id_classification, inventory.case_series, 
       inventory.case_id, inventory.comments, inventory.mac_address, 
       assortment.assortment_id, assortment.vendor, assortment.model, 
       assortment.type_id_dict_assortment_types, assortment.jim, 
       dict_assortment_types.type_id, dict_assortment_types.type_name, 
       personnel.personnel_id, personnel.first_name, personnel.last_name, 
       personnel.operational_id, personnel.seal_number, 
       personnel.military_grade, dict_classifications.classification_id, 
       dict_classifications.classification_abbr, 
       dict_classifications.classification_name, carrying_cases.description, 
       carrying_cases.location, inventory_comments.comment_id, 
       inventory_comments.comment, inventory_comments.inventory_id_inventory, 
       inventory.sdip_27, inventory.seal_number, inventory.seal_number, 
       inventory.description
FROM inventory_comments RIGHT JOIN (carrying_cases 
RIGHT JOIN ((((inventory INNER JOIN assortment 
       ON inventory.assortment_id_assortment = assortment.assortment_id) 
LEFT JOIN dict_assortment_types 
       ON assortment.type_id_dict_assortment_types = dict_assortment_types.type_id) 
LEFT JOIN personnel ON inventory.personnel_id_personnel = personnel.personnel_id) 
LEFT JOIN dict_classifications ON inventory.classification_id_classification
         = dict_classifications.classification_id) 
      ON (carrying_cases.case_id = inventory.case_id) 
     AND (carrying_cases.case_series = inventory.case_series)) 
      ON inventory_comments.inventory_id_inventory = inventory.inventory_id
ORDER BY inventory.inventory_id;
```

Thank You
Smok.

Comment: So, you can remove a record by deleting it in the linked table, but can't remove it in the query based on it? Or is _directly from rdbms_ in Postgresql itself?

Comment: Well, I've just tried to remove it using linked table - with success. Earlier i've manage to do that using pgAdminIII. What I cannot do is to use query or form with this query attached as datasource. Getting closer thank's to Ypur question... :)

Comment: Ah, certainly odd behaviour. I can't replicate it with the provided information, though. Please provide the query. You can try binding your form directly to the table.

Comment: I've put the query into the main post, as there is space limitation in the comment.

Comment: This query worked form me without any problem. And the most intresting fact, is that I didn't even touch the code of this query. The only thing I mess with was the form. :|. I've enabled statement logging into the RDBMS and i even cannot see any delete statements related to my activity.

Comment: Ah, I'm surprised Access lets you delete records of a query with that many joins (and doesn't return `Query not updateable`). You're probably off best deleting the records manually using either delete queries or recordsets. Even I don't know from which table a record should be deleted from looking at that query (I guess _inventory_comments_, but it might as well be one of the others).

Comment: In fact I was trying to delete from table _inventory_. Is there any better solution for Access instead of building such a complicated statement at a single query? Should I build cascade queries to avoid such an excessive complexity? Or better to leave it as is for display/update and just make a separate query (in vba) for deletion?

Comment: Well, that's a subjective question. Cascading queries might increase or decrease complexity depending on the situation. I usually attempt to bind forms directly to tables, without the use of any queries, and use subforms and domain aggregates to display related information, but that might not be a good fit for all databases.

Comment: Can you delete a record from this same query in a datasheet view?

Comment: Nope. But i could swear i could do that earlier. I've messed something up probably and don't know what was that. As for now I just switch to using SQL delete statement and it seems it works. After some test i'll write it here as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this question.

I found it most reliable to use delete queries with DoCmd.RunSql "DELETE * FROM table WHERE condition". This approach gives more controll over what happens and clear code (unless you hate SQL).

Thank you for all suggestions

Smok.